# Tomcat unable to start after modifying an Enum

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, enums

I have an Enum class which i have got deployed in tomcat.I have just added another constant in the Enum.But when i redeploy this Enum class to tomcat.It is showing this error.When i revert the changes it is working fine.But After i add this updated Enum the error prevails.

```
    SEVERE: Error starting static Resources
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base /opt/varbazaar/webapps/manager does not exist or is not a readable directory
    at org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.setDocBase(FileDirContext.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4286)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4455)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:546)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:637)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:563)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1277)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:321)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1061)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:585)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Mar 26, 2014 6:19:44 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error in resourceStart()
Mar 26, 2014 6:19:44 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error getConfigured
```

Comment: Is path /opt/varbazaar/webapps/manager correct?

Comment: The path never existed in the project

Comment: The problem occurs only when i deploy the modified Enum.I have checked the Enum it is working in my system but when i deploy this to the server it is showing this error

Comment: Where did it get from? This is not part of tomcat. Search tomcat home for it. What is tomcat home btw?

Comment: delete temp and work directories in TOMCAT_HOME directory and redeploy.